# ajax modal popup extender - control nesting

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am new to ajax and have been playing with the extenders. I have been making some webforms and using modal popup extenders on them for user feedback and notifications.

One question I have that I dont seem to be able to find an answer for is how do I control the way the popups nest?

So say I have 3 popups. How do I set some property to allow me to have 
Popup1 ontopof Popup2
Popup2 ontopof Popup3 
etc

Any help here would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance, 
Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by changing z-index via CSS or javascript

see http://forums.asp.net/p/1067281/2152419.aspx

In my personal experience for example CalendarExtenders dont show on top od ModalPopupextenders because of a bug in the latest release (30930).  I downgraded to (30512) and everything works.

P.D.  I am using .NET 3.5 and VS2008

Hope this helps